# Why my PMSM motor does not rotate?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I have implemented a FOC algorithm with Simulink -> C Code and an uE from ST (stm32f446re) but I am stuck the last 3 months and I cannot find the solution.

When I give Iq Soll as input, the motor turns for a moment (ca 1/8 of turn) and the Iq goes equal to Iq Soll and the error input for the PI Controller is equal to zero and the Vq output goes to zero and the motor stops to turn and stalls.

On the attached picture you can see the measurement, the blue color is the Iq, the yellow is the IqSoll and the green is the angle of the motor.

Any help? Have someone any ideas?

[image: Measurment]